# Panel position changes when enlarging browser window

Tags: html, css, asp.net

The situation i'm facing : 
i have an asp.net with a header, sidebar and another right sidebar. the thing is when i execute my website in browser and mimimize browser window. the sidebar on the left jumps on the content page and controls get all mixed. see picture for an idea.

Another problem is when i executed that website in a wider screen resolution the controls ( panels ) had a bigger margin and evertyhing look wider.

Any ideas how to fix this ?
Thank you in advance

[image]

EDIT:

Sidepanel ( right ) CSS code:

```
#droite
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 22.5em;
    right: 5%;
    width: 13%;
    background-color: White;
}
```

Comment: You'd probably need to post some code for this.  It looks like it's just a matter of CSS positioning, though.

Comment: Edited! added side bar css code

Comment: you need a media query to change the width property in smaller screen sizes. Right now it's 13%, thus it's really small in a small viewport

Comment: @flybear Could you please sugges some piece of code! never used media queries before and afraid i won't be able to deliver that before understanding media queries

Answer (score 0):

What I did on my website (firedrake969.github.io) was add some simple jQuery code to hide the sidebar whenever the window became too small.  If you don't mind using jQuery, I'd say that's the way to go.  However, if you don't want to use jQuery, I don't think `position:fixed` can have the bar hide just with CSS/HTML if the browser window gets too small.

Comment: I dont want to hide the panel! i want it to stay where it was placed when the window was in full-size. it's a panel to notify the user that they are online. hiding would be not logic.

Comment: Ah, so make it be on the far right of the document at all times?  You could use jQuery for that, too, or put everything in a wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something similar to this. the `max-width` can be set to any screen width you choose.

```
 @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
        #droite
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: 22.5em;
            left:5%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: White;
        }
    }
```